# Google Search Console "Clickable elements too close together" issue caused by using images in place of checkboxes

Tags: html, css, mobile, google-search-console

I am using images in place of checkboxes and because I need to hide the input["checkbox"] element, Google Search Console is flagging it as not mobile friendly, saying that the "Clickable elements [are] too close together".

Here is an example that shows how the code works:

```
<style>
    input[type=checkbox] {
        display: none;
    }
    img{
        border: 5px solid transparent;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked+img {
        border-color: #000;
    }
</style>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</label>
```

And here it is in codepen:

https://codepen.io/evan-appleby/pen/xxOjBag

When I unhide the checkbox, Google removes the issue, but not if I then cover the checkbox using a negative margin on the image. What can I do to fix this, without needing to remove the images entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premise of the question is incorrect. Google does not flag sites as having "clickable elements too close together" for using images in place of checkboxes. You can confirm that by going to [Google's Mobility-Friendly Test site](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly) and submitting the code block above.